# How to add sliding-effect transition to an element which appears (by adding 'position:fixed' at runtime) while scrolling the window?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this SSCCE, the class `scroll-header`, which has `position:fixed;`, is applied to `div.header` at runtime. I want it to have the effect of sliding down from the top edge of the screen when it appears. How can I do that?

I have tried applying `transition:position 1s ease 0s;` on `.header` but it does not seem to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("script.js is detected"); //check

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log("window onscroll being called."); //check
    if ($("div.view").visible(true)) {
      console.log("YES if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )"); //check
      $(".header").removeClass("scroll-header");
    } else {
      console.log("NO if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )"); //check
      $(".header").addClass("scroll-header");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.view {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: crimson;
}
.second {
  height: 2500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition:position 1s ease 0s;
}
.scroll-header {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
* {
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.visible/1.1.0/jquery.visible.min.js"></script>
<div class="view">.</div>
<div class="header">.</div>
<div class="second">.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is giving
 `top: 0px` attribute to .scroll-header class and removing position from transition property.

```
.scroll-header{
       top: 0px;
}

.header{
       transition: 1s;
}
```

Check this fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimish/v3wdqk5m/)

To set your required animation, you need to set header height to 0px and then you need to take it to your required header size of height (which is 70px in your case).

Please check this fiddle: [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimish/v3wdqk5m/2/)

Comment: That doesn't look like a slide-down transition effect =(

Comment: Sorry @Solace, I didn't get your question before. You can see my updated answer.

Comment: I thank you that you are putting time into this, but [the use of setTimeOut function](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/02/how-to-use-jquery-settimeout-function.html) does not seem to be animation. At first it actually looked like what I needed, but the transition/animation/sliding-down was too slow. I tried to change the last argument for `setTimeOut` to like 200, which results in weird behavior when it animates.

Comment: What the program does is that when the window is scrolled down, as soon as .view becomes 'invisible' from the current viewport (=the part of the screen/document/page you can see at a given time), the class scroll-header is added to .header. Now this class scroll-header has position:fixed (and background-color:yellow;), which implies that while scrolling the window down, as soon as the crimson colored .view div is out of the current viewport, the yellow bar at the top of the screen appears....

Comment: ... I want to animate the appearance of this yellow bar. I want it to look like it is sliding down from the upper edge of screen.

Comment: You have to manage transition css property and timeout both at the same time. Please check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jimish/v3wdqk5m/5/

Comment: [Please see here the effect, _and the neatness in the effect_ I was looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/bfp08nbw/1/). Thank you so very much for your time. I am upvoting your answer.

Comment: Totally forgot these two functions. Thank you @Solace for sharing this. You can edit this answer also. otherwise I ll do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution by Solace with jQuery animation. SlideUp() | SlideDown()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("script.js is detected");//check



$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log("window onscroll being called.");//check
    if ( $("div.view").visible(true) ) {
        console.log("YES if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )");//check
        //$(".scroll-header").animate({"height": "0px"}, 350);
      $(".scroll-header").slideUp();
    } else {
        console.log("NO if ( $(\"div.view\").visible(true) )");//check
        //$(".scroll-header").animate({"height": "70px"}, 350);
        $(".scroll-header").slideDown();
    }
});

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfp08nbw/1/

Comment: You asked: "I want it to have the effect of sliding down from the top edge of the screen when it appears. " what i'm missing?

Comment: What the program does is that when the window is scrolled down, as soon as `.view` becomes 'invisible' from the current viewport (=the part of the screen/document/page you can see at a given time), the class `scroll-header` is added to `.header`. Now this class `scroll-header` has `position:fixed` (and background-color:yellow;), which implies that while scrolling the window down, as soon as the crimson colored `.view`  div is out of the current viewport, the yellow bar at the top of the screen appears....

Comment: ... I want to animate the appearance of this yellow bar. I want it to look like it is sliding down from the upper edge of screen.

Comment: so your script works good, you just need the animation on the ".scroll-header" whenever you add it?

Comment: Yep. Actually I ended up going about it in another way, by making a few changes. In a nutshell I got the effect by using `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`. You can [see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/bfp08nbw/1/).

Comment: Nice, you did good. Sorry i hadn't time to do it last days :)

Comment: i will add your code to my response so people can find the solution if they are searching for it